# Tag synonyms: shared-objects and dynamic-linking

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I don't think we need to make the fine distinction between [shared-objects](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shared-objects) and [dynamic-linking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-linking). My preference is for [dynamic-linking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-linking) to be the main tag and [shared-objects](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shared-objects) to be the synonym. I haven't gone to see if there are other similar tags.

Comment: I say make it so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synonym approved. Do these need to be merged as well?

Comment: Yes please. What use are non-merged synonyms anyway?

Comment: @Gilles All done.